# How can I get the Item Renderer that is at the top of the viewport in a Flex Spark List?

Tags: list, apache-flex, tree, itemrenderer

I have a Flex Spark List (well it's a Tree to be precise but it renders as a list) and as I'm scrolling through it I want to provide information about the item that is currently at the top of the list in context to the viewport. So this could be the 100th item in the list depending on how far you've scrolled down.

Comment: you can't access the itemRenderer. But you can access the item, probably like Faheemitian mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
listProvider.getItemAt(list.scrollPositionToIndex(list.horizontalScrollPosition,
                                                  list.verticalScrollPosition));
```

Comment: I'd love to mark this answer as correct but scrollPositionToindex is not being recognised as a method of my List. Maybe it's deprecated. More soon ...

Comment: My bad. It is halo list method. You should check scroller for spark list